# Complement of a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need your help in the following Lemma I.4.2 from Hartshorne:

> Let $Y$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$ given by the equation $f(x_1,...,x_n)=0$. Then $\mathbb A^n\setminus Y$ is isomorphic to the hypersurface $H$ in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ given by $x_{n+1}f=1$. In particular $\mathbb A^n\setminus Y$ is [isomorphic to an] affine [variety], and its affine ring is $k[x_1,...,x_n]_f$.

In the proof one defines $\varphi(a_1,...,a_{n+1})=(a_1,...,a_n)$. I see that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. I have the following questions:

1) How does $\varphi$ "correspond" to the ring homomorphism $k[x_1,...,x_n]\to k[x_1,...,x_n]_f$ and what does it look like? I calcutated something, which does not seem useful, so I would appreciate your thoughts.

2) In the Lemma, I wonder how $\mathbb A^n\setminus Y$ can be (in whatever sense) affine? Being a hypersurface Y is perfectly affine itself, and how can the (open) complement be affine again? One does even use this in deducing that its coordinate ring is the same as $A(H)$.

Comment: @AlexR $Y$ is an affine hypersurface by assumption.

Comment: If we take $\mathbb A^1\setminus \{0\}$, then it's clear that $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}\cong \{xy=1\}\subset \mathbb A^2$. For me, the isomorphisme just send the hypersurface $Y$ to the "infinity".

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is the reverse of what you say in 2). You've shown that the complement of $Y$ is affine with the same coordinate ring as $H$ by showing it's isomorphic to $H$. Because of examples like this one-the complement of $Y$ is not closed-we usually define affine varieties as those isomorphic to a closed subset of affine space. As to 1): from the map $\varphi:H\to \mathbb A^n$ we get a dual map $\varphi^\#: k[x_1...x_n]\to k[x_1...x_n]_f$ sending $x_i$ to $x_i$.

Comment: So my confusion occured from the "wrong" definition of affine, namely being (irreducible) algebraic set = zero locus? Do all Proposition for irreducible algebraic sets also apply for affine sets in the sense you mentioned? Regarding the dual map, I would kindly ask you to help me with the calculation. I know, $\varphi$ induces a ring hom. $O(\mathbb A^n)=k[x_1,..,x_n]\to O(H)$ via $g\mapsto g\circ \varphi$. Why is $O(H)=k[x_1,..,x_n]_f$ and how do I get there calculating $g\mapsto g\circ \varphi$? Thanks a lot, I'm really stuck here...

Comment: I don't know whose definition that is: an algebraic set is not the same as an affine variety. But if that's the definition you've seen then yes, it's not "right." All reasonable facts about algebraic sets are true for affine varieties, where "reasonable" means "invariant under isomorphism."

Comment: That Definition can be found e.g. in Hulek, but thanks for your comment. Still, I don't see why $im(\varphi^\#)\subset k[x_1,...,x_n]_f$. Why does $1/f$ occur?